# Is it posible to make a random case chooser in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I mean for example use a normal case switch but instead of the case being selected by a user being chosen randomly

```
def switch_demo(argument):

    switcher = {

        1: "January",

        2: "February",

        3: "March",

        4: "April",

        5: "May",

        6: "June",

        7: "July",

        8: "August",

        9: "September",

        10: "October",

        11: "November",

        12: "December"

    }
```

and somehow make it random to choose, i mean the case is chosen randomly. For example: generate a random number this being the number of the case or something like that.

Comment: Why are you using a `switch` statement instead of just using the number as an index into a list?

Comment: Since when does Python have a `switch` statement?

Comment: This doesn't look like Python at all, it looks like JavaScript.

Comment: I'm sry @barmar I'm not as smart as you are, i'm just a newbie trying to learn hope you understand it. Thanks flr the help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you wanted to do with it, but you don't need to do it, you could do it like this:

```
import random

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

rand_month_choice = random.choice(months)
print(rand_month_choice) #prints the random choice
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible, but there are probably better ways of going about it. For example, you could simply go:

```py
from random import randint
month = randint(1,12)

case (month)...
```

I would suggest using a list to store this information, since this isn't really an appropriate use-case (no pun intended) for cases. Example 2 would be my choice since it's fast, understandable and easy to type.

**Example 1**

```py
from random import randint

months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

months_string = months[randint(0,11)] # 0-11 because the list starts from index 0
```

**Example 2**

```py
from random import choice

months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

monthstring = choice(months)
```